# Performance of bitwise operators in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

What is the fastest way to make the last 2 bits of a byte zero?

```c
x = x >> 2 << 2;
```

OR

```
x &= 252;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I think the real question is: Will the compiler be able to optimize the first case into the second case? You'll have to check the assembly to find out.

Comment: `&=` is a single operation, where shifting right then left is two operations. I agree: look at the assembly to be certain.

Comment: @Mysticial I guess the #2 is a winner in either case then :-)

Comment: Ok, I'll just go with the latter.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Maybe not in terms of readability though. But yeah, on nearly all modern processors, AND is at least as fast as shift.

Comment: Fwiw, *both* compile to `andl $0xfc, reg`, which `reg` being whatever register loaded the byte to begin with. (clang 3.4 on x86)

Comment: the only time the second way would be slower would be on a weird architecture like sparc64 if you were zeroing out the bottom two bits of a 64 bit register (this might happen if you wrote the line as `x &= ~3;`).

Comment: Difficult to tell. The second form is more obvious in terms of readbility (actually 0xfc is even better). But anyway, modern compilers should generate the most efficient code for the given processor.

Comment: You've written the code both ways. If you want to know which way is faster **run the code and then you'll know**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on many factors, including the compiler, the machine architecture (ie processor).

My experience is that

```
x &= 252; // or...
x &= ~3;
```

are more efficient (and faster) than

x = x >> 2 << 2;

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is smart enough, it might replace

```
x = x >> 2 << 2;
```

by

```
x &= ~3;
```

The later is faster than the former, because the later is only one machine instruction, while the former is two. And all bit manipulation instructions can be expected to execute in precisely one cycle.

---

Note:
The expression `~3` is the correct way to say: A bit mask with all bits set but the last two. For a one-byte type, this is equivalent to using `252` as you did, but `~3` will work for all types up to `int`. If you need to specify such a bitmask for a larger type like a `long`, add the appropriate suffix to the number, `~3l` in the case of a `long`.

Comment: are you sure the last one is one machine instruction?

Comment: @staticx Yes, I am. The expression `~3` is constant, the compiler calculates the correct constant for you.

Comment: I dumped the assembly using gcc and they produce identical programs

Comment: dumped with: `gcc -O2 -S -c test.c`

Comment: @cmaster as i mentioned above, the second one is not always a single instruction